# Install nodejs with php exec

Tags: php, node.js, ftp

I just bought a domain with some space, but my provider not supporting nodejs.
I searched a lot, how could I build it on the server, but of course, to make, I need so privileges, so now I'm stuck here.

How could I use nodejs (or other server side Javascript engine) to run javascript?

I have FTP access to the server, but nothing more.

Comment: there is no way you can install node with ftp.

Comment: do you have ssh ?? google it .. 
https://www.google.com/search?q=installing+node+on+shared+host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just can't.
If your provider doesn't give privileges to do it you are stuck :(